# Is using a relational DB for storing votes and (misc accessed resources) overkill?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, relational-database, database, nosql

Say I am writing a forum component for a site and would like to keep track of what topics/questions a user accesses so that other topics/questions can be recommended based on said users previous choices.

I'd imagine one individual data/row is not very important, where it'd absolutely necessitate ACID properties on every single entry; not to mention when the user-base grows large(on the order of millions, or tens of millions), this data set(of votes and/or accessed topics) will surely explode. Is this then a case for using say, MongoDB? What is the advisable general approach for storing this type of data?

Answer (score 2):

Tens of millions of rows is not a big deal for RDBMS, you can definitely use it for that.

However you might be right that you don’t need most of the features. AFAIK systems like this are usually implemented by simply logging access data into a store (log file, cassandra, …) and use batch jobs to analyze the logged data and create suggestions or relations between the blogs, which can be stored afterwards. The reason for this is, that you need rather complicated algorithms, which have to consider all the data, in order to get information you want.

Because a simple SQL query won’t give you the necessary answer, and the read access time to the store isn’t too relevant for a batchjob you can easily use write optimized datastructures like the already mentioned log and cassandra.